# clicking keeps redirecting to same page

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

I was working on a wordpress site locally, everything was working until today when I login to the site frontpage and try clicking on a link it redirects the same page.. I tried to undo all my code changes for today, and tried updating permalinks.. I disabled all plugins but no success. any idea what could be the caus of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this happens on your homepage, then go and see index.php. If your problematic link is generated with the_permalink(), at least you will know the problem is there. Otherwise, give more info (source code, the page where this is happening, is it happening to every link on every page, etc.)

Comment: thanks for you reply.
I changed the permalink options to default and it is now working. But when I change it back to "Day and name" option, it keeps redirecting on the hompage, however, the page link shows on the address bar.. any idea?